# Error using parted and need for restoring via initramfs

Tags: partitioning, initramfs-tools

I was using `parted` in a virtual machine and I issued a wrong command reducing the size of last partition of a disk. I reduced it of 170GB (from 107 to 90).
After rebooting I realized the problem when initrams prompted.
It is now reporting that:

> the filesystem size (according to superblock) is 22591744 blocks.
> The physical size of the device is 18350256 blocks.

How can I restore the situation? I tried to use e2fsck but I cannot figure how to put the end of the partition back (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I made a fresh install on the same root and I preserved the home directory.
I created a user with the same name and used chown to grant such user rw privileges.
Also, I had to manually edit fstab file to mount the pre-existing partition (recovered the old UUID).